# Jasmine test a callback passed to an anonym function

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-jasmine, aurelia

Hellow,

I have something like

```
export class Api {
    callHttpClient(url, options, settings) {
        this.httpClient.configure(callbackObjectInstance => {
            callbackObjectInstance.method();
        }); // And then some code
    }
}
```

How could I spyOn the callbackObject.method with Jasmine test framework ?

Thank you

Comment: You can spy on the class prototype of that `callbackObjectInstance`

Answer (score 0):

This should work as one approach.

```
describe('Given the API', function(){
    let api;
    let callback;
    beforeEach(function(){
        api = new Api();
        callback = {
            method: function() { }
        };
        spyOn(callback, 'method');
        spyOn(api.httpClient, 'configure').and.returnValue(callback);
    });

    it('should call method', function(){
        api.callHttpClient(something, something, something);
        expect(callback.method).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```